# Vue.js - Loading service - Element UI

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to use the loading service of `Element UI` framework.
I read the [documentation](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/loading) but I have hard time to figure out how to use it.

Let's take an example: how to display the loading only in the dialog when pressing on the `confirm` button of this `dialog`

https://jsfiddle.net/5xmoxwsy/1/

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add ref to dialog:

```
 ref="dialog"
```

Bind click to method in vm:

```
 @click="Confirm"
```

Methods:

```
methods: {
    Confirm() {
        var self = this;
        var loadingInstance = window.ELEMENT.Loading.service(
        {
            target: self.$refs.dialog.$el.querySelector('.el-dialog')
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.dialogFormVisible = false;
            loadingInstance.close();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jazdrood/)